# convert string num to number javascript

Tags: javascript

I was ask a question in an interview to convert a string number to a number.
eg : My string is "TEN" . and I have to convert it to number 10.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers

Comment: I think this link explains some stuff, I am gonna try this out. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if (string === "TEN") value = 10;

Comment: This is it, the problem's been solved. We can all go home now.

Comment: Actually , they mentioned that think of it as you have a file that contains hundred thousand strings . If I go by If else statements. It will not be an efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the interviewer's question. He meant getting the number that is currently in a string, not getting the number that is currently spelled out in a string.

But this has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090577/2725684