# Get Integer from number-string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert words to numbers in JavaScript?

As an example is there a javascript/jQuery library/plugin that will take a string "one hundred and two" and return the int 102.

```
var myInt = stringToInt("one hundred and two");
console.log(myInt);
=> 102
```

I specifically require a string-to-number conversion and not number-to-string conversion. Suggested solutions have come up short:

```
jsfiddle.net/joepegler/g0vwy44n
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a number to its string representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it should not be very difficult to do it yourself as an exercise, here's a script that does that

http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm

EDIT : I misread your question, you wanted the opposite. Well, check this answer instead then https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014376/4651083

Comment: 0/3: https://jsfiddle.net/joepegler/g0vwy44n/

Comment: @JoeAustin try this.
https://jsfiddle.net/g0vwy44n/1/

you will have to check in the console, as I have put some `console.log()`s in there

Comment: Nevermind. Works. Thank you

Comment: @JoeAustin The alerts where returning `undefined`, because `stringToNum` was not returning anything. I corrected that here https://jsfiddle.net/g0vwy44n/2/