# React/Javascript - Need a better solution for progress bar logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have progressbar in my project which takes in a range of values and i have added validation according to that. it is working but seems a lot of repetition. Need a better solution. Here is the code :-

```
const ProgressBar = ({ price }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bar">
      {price === 1 && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <span className="percentage one" />
          <span className="percentage two" />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      {price === 2 && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <span className="percentage one" />
          <span className="percentage two" />
          <span className="percentage three" />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      {price === 3 && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <span className="percentage one" />
          <span className="percentage two" />
          <span className="percentage three" />
          <span className="percentage four" />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So the price above can be 1,2,3 or 4 and I am making checks according to the number and then rendering a range of spans with the classes one, two, three, four. If a number is 2 then it will render 2 spans with class one and two. Can someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: `const ProgressBar = ({ price }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bar">
      <span className=\`percentage-${price}\` />
    </div>
  );
};`
And create the correspondent CSS classes that match the output you want through CSS properties. You could even just need one HTML element (the div) depending on the design.

Comment: @Dez but the price is a Number, not a string. Plus I need spans as per the number. If price is 3 then I need 3 spans with classes one, two, three

Comment: @MontyGoldy in the example you gave, price of 3 gives 4 spans. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
const ProgressBar = ({ price }) => {
  return (
    <div className='bar'>
      {price >= 0 && <span className="percentage one" />}
      {price >= 1 && <span className="percentage two" />}
      {price >= 2 && <span className="percentage three" />}
      {price >= 3 && <span className="percentage four" />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work? (Updated to add old class names).

```
const ProgressBar = ({ price }) => {
  const n = price + 1;
  const temp = Array(n).fill();

  const map = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four',
  }

  return (
    <div className="bar">
      <React.Fragment>
        {temp.map((_, i) => {
          return <span className={`percentage${map[i]}`} />;
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick, but it changed the span className from 'percentage one' to 'percentage1', 'percentage two' to 'percentage2', etc.

Comment: Yeah, you can just change the classes in CSS accordingly, or add in a map to this function if you must have those class names.

Comment: Or use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers
if the progress bar is going to go from 1 to 100.