# How to turn words into whole numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm in need of a function that takes in a string and turns words that are equal to a number into an integer.'one five seven three' -> 1573

Comment: Can you show a list of example? Why don't you use a library that can humanize number ? Otherwise, a simple Map would do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Words to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const numWords = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

const changeStrToNum = str => {
  let num = '';
  str.split` `.forEach(numWord => {
    num += numWords.indexOf(numWord);
  });
  return +num;
};

console.log(changeStrToNum('one five seven three'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object with the digit names and their values and return a new number.

```js
var words = { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9 },
    string = 'one five seven three',
    value = +string
        .split(' ')
        .map(w => words[w])
        .join('');        

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Upvoted yours because it's probably better to use O(1) lookup on an object literal rather than `indexOf` on an array in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it seems similar to with [JavaScript numbers to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words) you could invert this code for your use case

Posting gist with code for reference https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/7848621/ab5fa3df8280f718c2e5263a7eabe004790e7e20

Comment: If it is a dupe flag it as such. But it isn't, the OP is looking for the inversed operation.

Comment: Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can split first on space and than use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let words  = { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9 }
let string = 'one five seven three'
let value  = string
             .split(' ')
             .reduce((o, i) => o + words[i] ,'')      

console.log(value);
```