# how to multiply the value of a string to number in javaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I write a function in JavaScript that takes two parameters (a number and a "string" for e.g. 4 and "two") returns the sum of both multiplied.
if num = 4 and string = "three" then the function should return 12 as an int. I guess what I am asking is how do I get to convert the string number "two" to int 2.

Comment: There isn't an in-built function for turning number words into numbers.

Comment: Hi, So there is not native method to work with them, you have to manually run it with a switch statement, or put them in a array and take the index of the word and add 1 to it and then further proceed.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Words to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly if you npm install words-to-numbers you should be able to use that to convert your second parameter.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/words-to-numbers

Comment: This answer already exists in the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

something like this is the only way I can think of:

```
function convertStringToNumber(string) {
   if(string === 'one')
     return 1;
   if(string === 'two')
     return 2;
   if(string === 'three')
     return 3;
  /* keep going... */
}
```