# Change the class of div based on that value's position in array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

If I have an array of numbers split out like this:

```
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four, 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
```

And I have a div with class **"four"** and a pair of buttons:

```
<button id="buttonOne"></button>
<div class="four"></div>
<button id="buttonTwo"></button>
```

How can I make **buttonOne** reduce the class to "three" and **buttonTwo** increase it to "five"? I know this is probably kids stuff but any explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Words to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980087/javascript-words-to-numbers)

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to make an effort and show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Get the index of the element's `className` in the array, add/subtract 1, then get the item at the index of the result:

```js
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];

const div = document.querySelector('div');
buttonOne.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newClass = list[list.indexOf(div.className)-1]
  div.className = newClass;
  console.log(newClass);
})
buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newClass = list[list.indexOf(div.className)+1]
  div.className = newClass;
  console.log(newClass);
})
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne">reduce</button>
<div class="four"></div>
<button id="buttonTwo">increase</button>
```

If you want the class names to cycle (e.g, if the `div` has the `seven` class and clicking the 'increase' button causes the class name to become `one`), simply check whether the index is equal to `0` or the length of the array minus 1:

```js
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];

const div = document.querySelector('div');
buttonOne.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var index = list.indexOf(div.className);
  var newClass = list[index == 0 ? list.length-1 : index - 1]
  div.className = newClass;
  console.log(newClass);
})
buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var index = list.indexOf(div.className);
  var newClass = list[index == list.length - 1 ? 0  : index + 1]
  div.className = newClass;
  console.log(newClass);
})
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne">reduce</button>
<div class="four"></div>
<button id="buttonTwo">increase</button>
```

Comment: It would be better to use `this.nextElementSibling` and `this.previousElementSibling`. In a real application there won't be a single `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

Here handled some UX cases also, like disabling a button, when there is no action.

```js
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];
var listlength = list.length-1;
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("four")[0];
var btnOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var btnTwo = document.getElementById("buttonTwo");
btnOne.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var eleIndex = list.indexOf(ele.getAttribute("class"));
  var classname = list[--eleIndex];
      ele.setAttribute("class", classname);
      ele.innerHTML =classname;
      if(eleIndex == 0){this.disabled=true;return false};
      btnTwo.disabled = false;
});

btnTwo.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var eleIndex = list.indexOf(ele.getAttribute("class"));
  var classname = list[++eleIndex];
      ele.setAttribute("class", classname);
      ele.innerHTML = classname;
      if(eleIndex ==listlength){this.disabled=true;return false};
      btnOne.disabled = false;
});
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">Prev</button>
<div class="four" style="float:left;">four</div>
<button id="buttonTwo" style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```js
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'];

//  create variables for the DOM nodes you care about
const div = document.querySelector('div.four');
const buttonOne = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById('buttonTwo');

//  a function that returns the current class and its position in the array
const currentClass = () => {
    const className = div.className;
    const index = list.indexOf(className);
    return {className, index};
};

const setClass = (index) => {
    div.className = list[index];
};

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    setClass( currentClass()['index'] -1 );
});

buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    setClass( currentClass()['index'] +1 );
});
```

```css
button::before {
  content: attr(id);
}

div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne"></button>
<div class="four"></div>
<button id="buttonTwo"></button>
```